# How do I find the KL Divergence of samples from two 2D distributions?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Suppose I had two 2D sets of 1000 samples that look something like this:

[image]

I'd like to have a metric for the amount of difference between the distributions and thought the KL divergence would be suitable.

I've been looking at sp.stats.entropy(), however from this answer:

[Interpreting scipy.stats.entropy values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26743201/interpreting-scipy-stats-entropy-values)
it appears I need to convert it to a pdf first. How can one do this using a 4 1D arrays?

The example data above was generated as follows:

```
dist1_x = np.random.normal(0, 10, 1000)
dist1_y = np.random.normal(0, 5, 1000)

dist2_x = np.random.normal(3, 10, 1000)
dist2_y = np.random.normal(4, 5, 1000)

plt.scatter(dist1_x, dist1_y)
plt.scatter(dist2_x, dist2_y)
plt.show()
```

For my real data I only have the samples, not the distribution from which they came (although if need be one could calculate the mean and variance and assume Gaussian).
Is it possible to calculate the KL divergence like this?

Comment: My take on this would be to first do a 2D histogram of each of your data sets and then normalize it. In that way you will have a direct crude estimate of a PDF. Then use the KL divergence for the discrete case.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.422.5121) called "Kullback-Leibler Divergence Estimation of Continuous Distributions (2008)"

And you might find the open source implementation here https://gist.github.com/atabakd/ed0f7581f8510c8587bc2f41a094b518

Answer (score 0):

You can use KL divergence function from Pytorch. It can take inputs of of arbitrary shape (2d, 3d etc) provide they are of equal size.

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.kl_div.html#torch-nn-functional-kl-div

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was modelling them both as Gaussian distributions, as the KL divergence of two Gaussians is available in closed form: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60680/kl-divergence-between-two-multivariate-gaussians